# How do I calculate months between two dates in C

Tags: c, unix

I have a scenario where the monthly charges are calculated by the system over a span of 18 months. Say for example, the charges are 10$ ; the will then calculate $10/18 = $0.56 monthly.

If the customer cancels the service in the middle of the 18months period. I need to find the number of months he has used and refund the rest.
Ex: Customer created on Jun  2,2012 and cancel on Aug 13,2012, which means he used for 2 month completely and hence I need to refund `($10/18)* (18-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only going to be needed over a range of a few years - I would build a lookup table manually of the time_t value for the start of each month.

Then record the time_t they started the service, check the time_t now and then scan the table for the number of values between these.

ps. time_t is the 'C' stdlib basis for time functions, it's the number of seconds since 1970 and is used by all the functions in time.h

Comment: Martin, I don't get this , can you elaborate? I use time_t and epoch time in my system.

Comment: You need to count in something eg days but you may as well use seconds since that's what the time() function gives you. Then a table which lists time (ie seconds since 1970) for the start of each month, you just look down this sorted table to find which month a certain time() comes after and that tells you which month it was in.

Comment: how this will work in case the customer is  created in 10Aug,2010 and cancels on 10 Aug, 2012 ?

Comment: @dicaprio you make a table for the next 10years (or 20, or 50) it's only 120 entries!

Comment: customer might not accept for a solution where i say it will work for next 10 years or so.

Comment: I was thinking to add a counter and increment it every time a month passed for each service.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate amount of full months between two dates... So algorithm can be like this:

```
curDate  = fromDate;
curDate.month++;
totMonths = 0;
while (curDate < fromDate) {
    totMonths++;
    if (curDate.month == 12) {
        curDate.month = 1;
        curDate.year++;
    } else curDate.month++;
}
```

Comment: how do you handle different number of days in each month, and leap years?

Comment: It's easy part:

    const int DAYS_IN_MOTHS[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    daysInMonths = DAYS_IN_MOTHS[month];
    if (((year%4=0) && (year %100!=0) || (year%400=0))) daysInMonth++;

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method which will calculate this, however a better way of doing it is, writing an ADT to represent a date object which should do all the calculation on its own

```
int chargeFor(int createdD,int createdM,int createdY,int canceledD,int canceledM,int canceledY){
   int deltaD = canceledD - createdD;
   int deltaM = canceledM - createdM;
   int deltaY = canceledD - createdD;

   if( deltaD != 0 )
      return result = deltaY * 12 + deltaM + 1; 
   else 
      return result = deltaY * 12 + deltaM; 

}
```